# GLES20 - Fragment Shader with two float uniforms, works on some devices, only affects change in one in some others

Tags: android, opengl-es

The following is the GLSL Fragment Shader code I'm concerned about:

```
#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require
precision lowp float;

varying highp vec2 v_TexCoordinate;

uniform samplerExternalOES u_Texture;

uniform float uParamValue1; // hue
uniform float uParamValue2; // hue of replacing color

const float delta = 0.1;

vec3 rgb2hsv(vec3 c)
{
    vec4 K = vec4(0.0, -1.0 / 3.0, 2.0 / 3.0, -1.0);
    vec4 p = c.g < c.b ? vec4(c.bg, K.wz) : vec4(c.gb, K.xy);
    vec4 q = c.r < p.x ? vec4(p.xyw, c.r) : vec4(c.r, p.yzx);

    float d = q.x - min(q.w, q.y);
    float e = 1.0e-10;
    return vec3(abs(q.z + (q.w - q.y) / (6.0 * d + e)), d / (q.x + e), q.x);
}

vec3 hsv2rgb(vec3 c)
{
    vec4 K = vec4(1.0, 2.0 / 3.0, 1.0 / 3.0, 3.0);
    vec3 p = abs(fract(c.xxx + K.xyz) * 6.0 - K.www);
    return c.z * mix(K.xxx, clamp(p - K.xxx, 0.0, 1.0), c.y);
}

void main()
{
    vec3 texel = texture2D(u_Texture, v_TexCoordinate).rgb;
    vec3 texelHsv = rgb2hsv(texel);

    if(!(abs(texelHsv.x - uParamValue1) < delta))
    {
        texel = vec3(dot(vec3(0.299, 0.587, 0.114), texel));
        //texel = vec3(texture2D(inputImageTexture2, vec2(texel.r, .16666)).r);
    }
    else
    {
        texelHsv.x = uParamValue2;
        texel = hsv2rgb(texelHsv);
    }

    gl_FragColor = vec4(texel, 1.0);
}
```

The value of `uParamValue1` and `uParamValue2` is changed via two seekbars.

When I checked the uniform locations of `uParamValue1` and `uParamValue2`, they returned valid uniforms on both my Galaxy S6 and Xiaomi Mi 3W, 1 and 2 respectively.

However, when I move the slider that corresponds to `uParamValue1`, the shader doesn't seem to respond to the changes in Xiaomi Mi 3W, whereas in the Galaxy S6, it works fine.

Why is this, and how can I prevent it from happening?

Comment: I recommend you declare "highp"